# It's no sense to can't comment without gaining reputation

Tags: discussion

It's no sense to can't comment without gaining reputation. I've to comment that it's obligatory to say/write salawat when mentioning final Prophet Muhammad ﷺ name

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Further if you really have something to say then **answer**. Comments are intended for clarification. As you didn't mention what you are referring to it is hard to judge whether your intended "action" was an answer or clarification, but as written it sounds like the first, but Allah knows best. Site policies may not always please everyone, but they are valid.

Comment: You don't need to comment the Salawat, you can say it out loud as you read it.

Answer (score 7):

Users can't post comments on other people's posts unless they have 50 reputation. This is a network-wide policy that is explained e.g. here: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comments do not bump a thread to the main page and they also do not have review queues or voting etc. Hence it is difficult for the community to moderate them. If new users were allowed to post comments it would be exploited by spammers.